# What's the point of LEA EAX, [EAX]?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, instruction-set

```
LEA EAX, [EAX]
```

I encountered this instruction in a binary compiled with the Microsoft C compiler. It clearly can't change the value of EAX. Then why is it there?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, this is a release version of binary, so optimization should be on. Also, I'm using ollydbg for disassembling.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding C statement for this gem?

Comment: @Wikser: No. And this is not a one off case. I've seen one or two others like LEA EBX, [EBX] in the same binary. In fact, I'm look at the last one right now on my screen. Ollydbg shows the op-code for this one (LEA EBX, [EBX] that is) as "8D9B 00000000"

Comment: If that is a 64-bit binary then it's just a zero out the top 32 bits

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It is a `NOP`.

The following are typcially used as `NOP`. They all do the same thing but they result in machine code of different length. Depending on the alignment requirement one of them is chosen:

```
xchg eax, eax         = 90
mov eax, eax          = 89 C0 
lea eax, [eax + 0x00] = 8D 40 00
```

Comment: Actually, it's not strictly a `NOP`, because it introduces a data dependency on `EAX`. Modern CPUs detect this specific pattern as a `NOP` and ignore the data dependency, but some older CPUs might not.

Comment: Actually, the opcode for `nop` is `0x90`, which is the same as `xchg eax, eax`

Comment: well, it is wrong that "modern cpu's detect this specific pattern as a NOP", they still introduce _false_ data dependency chains. There are only some true NOP's out there where the decoders just don't introduce any data-dependencys.

Comment: @Quonux the [multi-byte NOPs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/307174) have been made official long time ago. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12564044/995714) has also listed Intel's official NOPs from 2 to 9 bytes

Answer (score 35):

From [this](http://www.strchr.com/machine_code_redundancy) article:

> This trick is used by MSVC++ compiler
>   to emit the NOP instructions of
>   different length (for padding before
>   jump targets). For example, MSVC++
>   generates the following code if it
>   needs 4-byte and 6-byte padding:
>
> 8d6424 00            lea [ebx+00],ebx 
>   ; 4-byte padding 8d9b 00000000
>   lea [esp+00000000],esp ; 6-byte
>   padding
>
> The first line is marked as "npad 4"
>   in assembly listings generated by the
>   compiler, and the second is "npad 6".
>   The registers (ebx, esp) can be chosen
>   from the rarely used ones to avoid
>   false dependencies in the code.

So this is just a kind of NOP, appearing right before targets of jmp instructions in order to align them.

Interestingly, you can identify the compiler from the characteristic nature of such instructions.

Comment: Saying it's a `NOP` is only half the answer (yet, oddly, the selected one).  Explaining why you'd want to do these `NOP`s is the complete answer.  Well done.

Comment: I encountered this using the MSVC++ compiler as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
LEA EAX, [EAX]
```

Indeed doesn't change the value of EAX. As far as I understand, it's identical in function to:

```
MOV EAX, EAX
```

Did you see it in optimized code, or unoptimized code?

Comment: It's optimized code alright. But how does that justify/explain this LEA?

Comment: @Frederick: had it not been optimized, I guess it would make sense if the compiler uses LEA for some sort of computation and a special case generated this redundant statement (this happens in unoptimized code)

Comment: This is a binary released to customers by my company. So it has to be the optimized version.

Comment: "So it has to be the optimized version". Not necessarily. What if they forgot to turn on `/O2`?

Comment: the LEA instruction could be execute faster on a Pentium 4 than a MOV instruction(and calculations are still today fast using LEA) so i would point this as a reason for LEA.