# MSVC compiler generates mov ecx, ecx that looks useless

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64

I have some C++ code that is being compiled to the following assembly using MSVC compiler v14.24:

```
00007FF798252D4C  vmulsd      xmm1,xmm1,xmm7  
00007FF798252D50  vcvttsd2si  rcx,xmm1  
00007FF798252D55  vmulsd      xmm1,xmm7,mmword ptr [rbx+28h]  
00007FF798252D5A  mov         ecx,ecx  
00007FF798252D5C  imul        rdx,rcx,0BB8h  
00007FF798252D63  vcvttsd2si  rcx,xmm1  
00007FF798252D68  mov         ecx,ecx  
00007FF798252D6A  add         rdx,rcx  
00007FF798252D6D  add         rdx,rdx  
00007FF798252D70  cmp         byte ptr [r14+rdx*8+8],0  
00007FF798252D76  je          applyActionMovements+15Dh (07FF798252D8Dh)
```

As you can see, the compiler added two

```
mov         ecx,ecx
```

instructions that don't make any sense to me, because they move data from and to the same register.

Is there something that I'm missing?

---

Here is a small Godbolt reproducer: https://godbolt.org/z/UFo2qe

```
int arr[4000][3000];
inline int foo(double a, double b) {
    return arr[static_cast<unsigned int>(a * 100)][static_cast<unsigned int>(b * 100)];
}

int bar(double a, double b) {
    if (foo(a, b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's an inefficient way to zero-extend ECX into RCX.  More efficient would be `mov` into a different register [so mov-elimination could work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an inefficient way to zero-extend ECX into RCX.  More efficient would be `mov` into a different register [so mov-elimination could work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all).

Duplicates of:

- [Why did GCC generate mov %eax,%eax and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910501/why-did-gcc-generate-mov-eax-eax-and-what-does-it-mean)
- [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)

But your specific test-case needs zero-extension for a slightly non-obvious reason:

x86 only has conversion between FP and *signed* integers (until AVX512).  FP -> `unsigned int` is efficiently possible on x86-64 by doing FP -> `int64_t` and then taking the low 32 bits as `unsigned int`.

This is what this sequence is doing:

```
vcvttsd2si  rcx,xmm1    ; double -> int64_t, unsigned int result in ECX
mov         ecx,ecx     ; zero-extend to promote unsigned to ptrdiff_t for indexing
add         rdx,rcx     ; 64-bit integer math on the zero-extended result
```