# Strange`lea` instruction

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, windbg

Its strange to *me*, so apologies for the iffy title. What is the purpose of this instruction?

```
lea esi, [esi]
```

I am not sure if you need any surrounding context or it can be explained in isolation. Let me know either way.

Comment: That's a nop, used as padding probably.

Comment: @Jester: Sorry, I don't follow. How does it help in padding?

Comment: It takes up bytes so the following instruction will be aligned appropriately.

Comment: Occupies space but doesn't alter the program behaviour: padding

Comment: That explains it. Could one of you fine folks hoist this as an answer so I can accept it or is it too much trouble?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this specific padding is used in Windows functions to allow for hot-patching.

Comment: @fuz that's a different one.

Comment: @Jester Oh yeah, that was `mov edi,edi`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703394/whats-the-point-of-lea-eax-eax